# Connection of android studio project to MySQL database server

Tags: java, android, mysql, mysql-workbench

I tried ro run my android studio project on Localhost server

```
package xyz.clicking.scenic.testymobd;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView text, errorText;
    Button show;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        errorText = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        show = findViewById(R.id.button);

        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    connect();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
 private Connection connect() throws SQLException {
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase";
            String user = "myusr";
            String password = "mypass";
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new SQLException("Database connection error.", e);
        }
    }

}
```

I'm tried in MySQL workbench this steps all data is just for example:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydatabase;
CREATE USER 'myusr'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'myusr';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase.* TO 'myusr'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

;
So, i tried to set ip like localhost, 127.0.0.1, 10.0.2.2
What i'm expecting : Just successful connection, tried also connect on clear Java it works but with Android Std other situation.
Every time i get tjis error
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.

Comment: You did not even tell where your server is running. You should have told that in first line of your post.

Comment: Please [reconsider your use of JDBC on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android?r=Saves_AllUserSaves).

Comment: 1)Don't use JDBC.  Use a web service.  2)none of those IPs will work because the db isn't running on the phone.  3)If you want to use a local db rather than a remote one, use SQLite which is built in.  But if you do need a remote one, do not connect to it directly.